# Expand mapping in SQL to own rows?

Tags: sql, mapping, expand

Say I have the table below

```
mytable
Name   HourlyValue
TC1    {0=1.519, 1=1.175, 2=2.471}
TC2    {0=1.200, 1=1.000, 2=1.115}
```

How do I expand the HourlyValue so that the table becomes this

```
mytable
Name   Hour   Value
TC1    0      1.519
TC1    1      1.175
TC1    2      2.471
TC2    0      1.200
TC2    1      1.000
TC2    2      1.115
```

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by using the below:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    key AS Hour,
    value AS Value
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(HourlyValue) AS r(key, value)
```